# How to return a JDBC ResultSet using Groovy

Tags: grails, jdbc, groovy

I am doing a report using JasperReport from Groovy+Grails and want to send the ResultSet to my report. The problem is the Jasper doesn't know the dataSource from Groovy+Grails. I am using this

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, parameterMap, new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet));
```

This class just receives a ResultSet object but I can't find the way to return a JDBC ResultSet from Groovy+Grails to pass to `JRResultSetDataSource()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groovy.sql.Sql` to create and execute sql queries and it also return a `ResultSet` object.

You can create a new `groovy.sql.Sql` instance using different strategies like using a existing sql connection, dataSource bean or by supplying the normal jdbc connection details. Look for more details [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html).

`executeQuery` and `executePreparedQuery` are two method that can be used to execute sql queries and will return a `Resultset`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working inside a service or a controller you can do this:

first you need to inject your datasource inside the service or controller:

```
def dataSource
```

And then inside the function that creates the jasper you can use something like:

```
 Sql sqlConn = new Sql(dataSource)
 String query = "SELECT * FROM my_table"
 sqlConn.executeQuery(query)
```